# GStreamer audio on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-creator, gstreamer

I try to use GStreamer on Android via Qt and C++. I already use GStreamer on these platforms but now I have an issues with the plugins:

```
G_BEGIN_DECLS
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(coreelements);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(audiotestsrc);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(audioconvert);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(androidmedia);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(playback);
G_END_DECLS
void MainWindow::play(){
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(coreelements);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(audiotestsrc);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(audioconvert);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(androidmedia);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(playback);

    GstElement *pipeline;
    GError *error = NULL;

    pipeline = gst_parse_launch("audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! androidmedia", &error);
    if (!pipeline) {
        ui->label->setText("error");
        return;
    }
    if(error != NULL){
        qDebug("GST error: ");
        qDebug(error->message);
        qDebug("GST end.");
    }else{
        qDebug("GST without errors");
    }


    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    ui->label->setText("Playing...");

}
```

With this variant of code I get

> undefined reference to 'gst_preset_get_type'

and I don't know with which library I need to link my app.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: this would be in libgstreamer-1.0.so (I checked with `readelf -Ws lib....so`), otherwise I have no exp with Android..

Comment: @otopolsky ok, I checked `libgstreamer-1.0.a` using this command and found `gst_preset_get_type` in the `File: libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstpreset.o)`, but I already link my project with `-lgstreamer-1.0`. So what I need to do now?